# Timestamp a Cell when a Condition is met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I'm completely new to scripts so I was wondering if anyone could assist me with the following:
I have a spreadsheet where Column D has the status of a project, and I would like Column H to populate with the current timestamp/date when Column D is populated with "Completed".

If the status changes from Compete to another value, the timestamp should disappear. It's a spreadsheet with multiple users so the timestamp trigger should apply regardless of who the user is.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's not clear how much you already know about Google Apps Script, so if you haven't done yet please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If Column D is "Completed" Column H is Date

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value == "Completed") {
    e.source.toast("Flag1")
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(new Date());
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value != "Completed") {
    e.source.toast("Flag2")
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank for your help here. I pasted this script and replaced "Your Sheet Name" with the actual name.
Once I ran the script I received the following error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ macros.gs:2


When I click on the Debug icon it says:
e: undefined
sh: undefined

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is an onEdit function and so it requires the event object in order to function properly.  So save it in the script editor and then go to your sheet and make the appropriate edits to test it..

Comment: Hi Cooper. Thanks for your quick reply. I went into the sheet and tried a test, but nothing happened. Do you have any thoughts as to what I may have done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try it again.  I made a couple of errors

Comment: HEY IT WORKS. Thank you.
FYI, when I press "Run", I get the same message: 
12:39:13 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onEdit @ Timestamp.gs:2

But I assume thats normal?

Also, I wanted to ask if it's possible to change the date format to say something like: 9/02/2022 15:10:26.


Right now, it's just 9/02/2022

Thank you.

Comment: Oh press run in script editor.  Yes you cannot run an onEdit(e) without supplying the event object.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I understand.
Also, I found the solution to the second part of my question, I just had to format the Column to "Date Time".
Thanks so much.

Comment: I returned it to a Date()